# How to remove terms from Google search results?

Tags: google-search

I used to be able to stop terms from appearing in my Google search results using the minus letter, but this no longer seems to work.

Is there a new way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does work, as a librarian I use it all the time. Try encasing the main search phrase in "" and then -keyword -keyword after it. e.g.

> "seal*" -navy -sport +antarctic

Make sure there is no space between the '-' and the keyword. Alternatively, if you aren't getting any joy use Advanced Search and do it in there.